# Can I import an entire library for one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree

I'm trying to understand the concept of tree shaking and I was thinking if I'm working on a project that used Material UI for example but the user like the way Ant Design calendar looks

Can I just install the entire thing and import only calendar size in my bundle?

Comment: Yes, if the library imports tree shaking then you can install the whole library, then specifically import the component you want and only that one will be in the bundle

Comment: How can I tell if a library is tree shakble or not tho? @Jayce444

Comment: You'll have to see if it says so in the documentation. If it supports direct importing of components then it's *probably* tree shakeable (though that's not a guarantee). You can also use the webpack bundle analyzer to look at your built bundle and see if it contains the entire library (by looking at file size for the particularly library and comparing it to total bundled library size): https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be the same for Bootstrap, Material UI or AntDesign. You should install this library than use it's component.
Example install Ant Design:

```
npm install antd
```

Now on ReactJS import components that you want to use:

```
import { DatePicker } from 'antd'
```

...

```
<DataPicker />
```

This is all you need to do for Bootstrap, MaterialUI etc